# Swift NSCoding enum of Hashable

Tags: swift, enums, nscoding

I would like to know how can I encode an enum made of Hashables? I know how to encode it using Codable, but in my case it has to be done by using NSCoding.
My enums are as following:

```
enum ItemCatalog: Hashable {
    case sword(Swords) 
    case shield(Shields)  
    case armor(Armors)  
}

enum Swords: String{  
    case sabre
    case xiphos
    case broadsword
}

enum Shields: String {
    case buckler
    case heaterShield
}

enum Armors: String {
    case studArmor 
    case chainmail 
    case plateArmor
}
```

I tried to encode it by:

```
override func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(catalogCode, forKey: "catalogCode")
}
```

and the app crashed with an error, therefore, I tried:

```
aCoder.encode(catalogCode.hashValue, forKey: "catalogCode")
```

the app will run without crashing but I'm not sure if it was the right way to encode it. Anyhow, when it comes to decoding it, I have no idea how to do it. I tried the following and the app crashed because it returned a nil:

```
required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        let catalogCode = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "catalogCode") as? ItemCatalog
        self.init(itemCatalogCode: catalogCode!)
}
```

Could someone please show me how to do it?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `NSCoder` is an Objective-C framework. It was never meant to handle things like Swift enums with associated values. If you really have to use `NSSecureCoding` in Swift, you will have to manually convert your enum values into something that can be encoded with `NSCoder`. This would be a lot simpler if your enums had Int or String raw values. Why do you need to support `NSSecureCoding`? Maybe there's a better solution.

Comment: @HangarRash Because I'm using SpriteKit as my framework and when a SKScene is loaded, it will only trigger "required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {}". It does not trigger "required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {} which goes with Codable.

Comment: Since there are no duplicate values between each sub enum, you can save the raw value. If they are duplicates, you can save "EnumName.RawValue" and make an init with that. Ie : You save a String, and read a String that you convert into your ItemCatalog value.